# Apache2 on Ubuntu server - Windows Domain

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, virtualhost

Hi this is probably a stupid question....but here it goes

I have an Ubuntu server (hostname: intranet) with apache2 running with virtual hosts. Lets call them "website1.intranet" and "website2.intranet".

The ubuntu server is on a Windows AD "domain.local"

When I try to access the virtual hosts with a hosts file pointing to the intranet IP address it works fine. Without the ip in the host file it does not work.
I really want others in the company to have access to it without having to add the server to their host file. So I thought it would be possible to get our DNS server to figure it out :)

I tried to add an A record to our DNS forward zone but it doesn't help. 
I'm a noob in all this but eager to learn :)

Our DNS and AD in on a Windows Server 2003 and probably could be set up better but I don't know if thats the problem or not.

Anyone out there that can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Ubuntu machine is known as intranet.domain.local in AD DNS, you could add a wildcard to it:

```
*.intranet.domain.local. IN A ip.of.the.ubuntu.box
```

NOTE that you must adjust the apache virtualhost Servernames accordingly.